# Set default application using command line

Tags: scripts, java, gnome-terminal, default-programs

How can I do **right click > File > Properties > Open with > Set as default** in the terminal?

I created a java app and an installation script for it. I would like to run my app by double click. So I create myProgram.desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/` (I did it because base `JRE.desktop` is using the wrong working directory). If I set it up in the GUI, everything is working, but I am not able to do it from the terminal (basically from my script).

Answer (score -2):

To make a default application that opens a file from the GUI do the following:

1. Right click on the file and choose properties.
2. Select the open With tab.
3. Select your desired application
4. Click Set as Default

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that, but my question is: How to do it from the terminal?